# Python reading binary values as ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I am using python 3.7. For some reason my code is reading the binary files as string inputs instead of binary objects. I can't figure out what is causing this and what I have written seems to match what other people are using in their solutions to reading a binary file.

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte:
        print(byte)
        print(type(byte))
        byte = f.read(1)
```

I think it may be due to how the code that wrote the binary file is written. Here is the  code for that :

```
messages=[[101,1,0,2,10,3,1,4,0],
      [101,1,1,2,9,3,1,4,0],
      [101,1,2,2,8,3,1,4,0],
      [101,1,3,2,7,3,1,4,0],
      [101,1,4,2,6,3,1,4,0],
      [101,1,5,2,5,3,0,4,1],
      [101,1,6,2,4,3,0,4,1],
      [101,1,7,2,3,3,0,4,1],
      [101,1,8,2,2,3,0,4,1],
      [101,1,9,2,1,3,0,4,1],
      [101,1,10,2,0,3,0,4,1]]

newFile = open("testData.bin", "wb")
for message in messages:
    line=[]
    for value in message:
        bValue=value.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big',signed=False)
        line.append(bValue)
        newFile.write(bValue)
```

My current results is that the first line prints out the ascii value of the file, and the the second print says that is a string.

Comment: So after exploring the code it seems like it is mainly due to the code that is writing the binary values, since it is converting the 101 to e which is equivalent ascii value instead of the binary value. Still not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When displaying the representation of a `byte`, the Python interpreter will display the ASCII character that corresponds to the `byte` is the value of the byte is in the range 0 - 127 and the character can be represented.  Otherwise it will display the hex escape.

Take the first list from `messages` as an example.

```
>>> m = messages[0]
>>> m
[101, 1, 0, 2, 10, 3, 1, 4, 0]
>>> bs = b''.join(x.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big', signed=False) for x in m)
>>> bs
b'e\x01\x00\x02\n\x03\x01\x04\x00'
```

101 and 10 are displayable  ASCII characters

```
>>> chr(101)
'e'
>>> chr(10)
'\n'
```

so you see the ASCII equivalents in the byte sequence.  0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 are not displayable, so the hex escapes are displayed instead.

Comment: If I generate your file and read from it using your code, `print(type(byte))` results in `<class 'bytes'>` for me.